# For Responder in Request-Reply pattern, which queue it should use to create the consumer?

Tags: ibm-mq

For example, I have IBM MQ that have REQUESTQ and RESPONSEQ, when I submit the request to the REQUESTQ, I need to get the response from RESPONSEQ. Based on this code below:

```
package requestReply;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;

import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

/*
 * Implementation of requester class
 */
class Requestor implements Runnable {
       private Thread t;
       private String threadName;

       Requestor( String name){
           threadName = name;
           System.out.println("Creating Thread:" +  threadName );
       }

       public void run() {
            JmsConnectionFactory cf = null;
            Connection connection = null;
            Session session = null;
            Destination reqQ = null;
            Destination repQ = null;
            MessageProducer producer = null;
            MessageConsumer consumer = null;

            try {
              // Create a connection factory
              JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
              cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

              // Set the properties
              cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
              cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM2");

              // Create JMS objects
              connection = cf.createConnection();
              session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

              // Create destination to send requests
              reqQ = session.createQueue("queue:///REQUESTQ");
              // Create destination to read replies
              repQ = session.createQueue("queue:///REPLYQ");

              // Create producer
              producer = session.createProducer(reqQ);

              // Create a request message
              Message requestMessage = session.createTextMessage("Requesting a service");
              // Tell the responder where to put replies.
              requestMessage.setJMSReplyTo(repQ);
              // Send it off
              producer.send(requestMessage);

              // Get only that reply that matches my request message id.
              String selector = "JMSCorrelationID='" + requestMessage.getJMSMessageID()+"'";

              // Create consumer with selector
              consumer = session.createConsumer(repQ, selector);

              // Start the connection
              connection.start();

              // Get the message
              Message receivedMessage = consumer.receive(35000);
              if(receivedMessage != null)
                  System.out.println("\nRequestor received message:\n" + receivedMessage);
              else
                  System.out.println("No message received");
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(threadName);
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
       }

       // Start thread
       public void start ()
       {
          System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
          if (t == null)
          {
             t = new Thread (this, threadName);
             t.start ();
          }
       }

    }

/*
 * Implementation of Responder class
 */
class Responder implements Runnable {
       private Thread t;
       private String threadName;

       Responder( String name){
           threadName = name;
           System.out.println("Creating Thread: " +  threadName );
       }

       public void run() {
            JmsConnectionFactory cf = null;
            Connection connection = null;
            Session session = null;
            Destination reqQ = null;
            Destination repQ = null;
            MessageProducer producer = null;
            MessageConsumer consumer = null;

            try {
              // Create a connection factory
              JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
              cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

              // Set the properties
              cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
              cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM2");

              // Create JMS objects
              connection = cf.createConnection();
              session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
              reqQ = session.createQueue("queue:///REQUESTQ");

              // Create consumer to read requests
              consumer = session.createConsumer(reqQ);

              // Start the connection
              connection.start();

              // Loop to read requests and respond
              while(true){
              Message receivedMessage = consumer.receive(35000);
              if(receivedMessage != null){
                  System.out.println("\nResponder received message:\n" + receivedMessage);
                  repQ = receivedMessage.getJMSReplyTo();
                  producer = session.createProducer(repQ);
                  Message requestMessage = session.createTextMessage("Responder service");
                  requestMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(receivedMessage.getJMSMessageID());
                  producer.send(requestMessage);
              }
              else
                  System.out.println("No message received");
              }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(threadName);
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
       }

       public void start ()
       {
          System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
          if (t == null)
          {
             t = new Thread (this, threadName);
             t.start ();
          }
       }

    }

public class ReqRep {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Requestor req = new Requestor( "Requester");
        req.start();

        Responder rep = new Responder( "Responder");
        rep.start();
    }
}
```

[Code was copied from: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/jms_request_reply_sample?lang=en]

What I understand from this code is, when the `Requestor` thread submit request to the `REQUESTQ`, `Responder` will pull out the information from `REQUESTQ` and re-send it to the `RESPONSEQ`, so the `Requestor`  can get the actual response from `RESPONDERQ`?

I am asking this because when I actually tried, `Requestor` and `Responder` always hanging to get the response, that which make sense to me, because once the request sit in the `REQUESTQ`, the MQ service already get rid that message, process it and push to the `RESPONSEQ` already, and since `Requester` is waiting for `Responder`, and `Responder` cannot pull out any thing from `REQUESTQ`, that causing hanging. (Correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: Can you rephrase the title to be a question instead of stating you have a question? You're on Stack Overflow and asking a question, so state the point of your question up front. This helps other people find your question at a glance.

Comment: @tadman hopefully this title will make more sense to my question

Comment: On the right track now, thanks. Now someone who knows MQ will be more likely to see this and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it on my machine and it worked sometimes as expected, sometimes it was hanging 35 seconds until the messages were flowing.

It is a timing issue when starting the `Responder`. If the `Connection` and `Session` is setup too early, it does not see the messages in the first `receive` and only gets it after the first 35 seconds of waiting. To overcome this, just wait a little between `req.start()` and `rep.start()`, then it will work consistently.

I recommend to read the official IBM tutorials, for example [Point to point with JMS](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/develop-mq-jms/). As a plus point, it uses JMS 2.0 which make JMS programming simpler.